# Does a two-way short exact sequence split?

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence, direct-product

Suppose we have two short exact sequences, $0\rightarrow B\rightarrow A\rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ and $0\rightarrow C\rightarrow A\rightarrow B \rightarrow 0$.

Is there anything we can conclude about them? Do they necessarily split?

Alternatively, if $A/B\cong C$ and $A/C\cong B$, can we conclude that $A\cong B\times C$? If not, what are other needed conditions to make that conclusion?

Examples/counterexamples are appreciated.

Edit: A comment has pointed out that in general, no. But I'd love to get a comprehensive answer.

Comment: $0 \to {\mathbb Z}_2 \to {\mathbb Z}_4 \to {\mathbb Z}_2 \to 0$.

Comment: I didn't mention mention what algebraic structure $A, B, C$ were. I guess it doesn't matter, but if they do, I hope I can get an answer for each case (groups, rings, modules, etc.).

Comment: By rings, do you mean non-unital rings?

Comment: I was thinking of unitary rings because they're more common, but there is no reason for me to ignore non-unital ones. What's special about them that made you ask?

Comment: "short exact sequence of rings" doesn't really make sense. It makes more sense for non unital ones than for unital ones (what does $f\circ g = 0$ mean for unital rings ? ), but still not a lot of sense anyway

Comment: I think I remember seeing a question (here or on MO) where an answer pointed out that there existed exact sequences of the form $0\to A\to A\oplus B\to B\to 0$ that did no split (obviously this means $A\to A\oplus B$ is not the standard inclusion, and $A\oplus B\to B$ is not the standard projection); this also implies a negative answer.